# I am not able to install Talend open studio on Mac OS

Tags: talend

I am not able to install Talend open studio on Mac OS.
Error - The TOS_BD-macosx-cocoa executable launcher was unable to locate its 
companion shared library.

Comment: do you have the exact log?

Comment: this may help  https://www.talendforge.org/forum/viewtopic.php?id=2831

Comment: Just run into the same issue with Talend Open Studio (TOS_DI-20170623_1246-V6.4.1) on macOS Sierra (10.12.6).

Apparently, the default macOS Archive Utility app does not extract the installation archive properly. With Keka file extractor, the archive was extracted correctly and the issue "The TOS_BD-macosx-cocoa executable launcher was unable to locate its companion shared library" gone away.

Answer (score 1):

You just need to execute this command in TOS binaries folder : `xattr -c TOS_DI-macosx-cocoa.app`

Comment: That got past one error, only to fail without error message and refer to newly created log.

Answer (score 0):

Default macOS Archive Utility app does not extract the installation archive properly. 
Unzip using Keka - http://www.kekaosx.com/en/
Then Open Installer file.